# How can I create a working set inside a working set in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do you create a working set inside another working set in Eclipse? For example:

```
Comp102
   Assignments
    Assign1
    Assign2
    Assign3
   Labs
    Lab1
    Lab2
    Lab3
Comp103
   Assignments
    Assign1
    Assign2
    Assign3
   Labs
    Lab1
    Lab2
    Lab3
```

where Comp102 and Comp103 are two different working sets and Assignments and Labs are two working sets within Comp102 and Comp103.